# Not able to upgrade from 12.04 to 13.04 or above

Tags: upgrade

I am usng ubuntu 12.04 LTS want to upgrade to 13.04 or above. I have followed the steps provided in the ubuntu forum but that is not working for me. I run the update manager and it updates a whole lot of things but the os version never upgrades.

Please advise a solution. I am using Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 1):

please add a link for the steps you've followed so we can help, also try the following:

from `software center > Edit menu > Software Sources`: select the Updates tab. below you should find an option that says `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version`, This is probably set to Long Term support versions only, change it to any new version and try updating again. this MIGHT solve your problem.

But please notice that this will update to 13.04 then 13.10 not 13.10 directly. I would recommend downloading 13.10 iso and using it to update your system directly.